# How create List button like this Image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am confused about using the widget that is most appropriate for this display
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListView` widget this is best for this. like so

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Something'),),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildListTile(Icons.phone, 'Telepon', "Kode verfikasi akan dikirim melalui telepon", Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
Divider(), // <-- this is added
            buildListTile(Icons.chat_bubble, 'SMS', "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur", Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
Divider(), // <-- this is added
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  ListTile buildListTile(leadingIcon, titleText, subtitleText, trailingIcon) {
    return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(leadingIcon),
            title: Text(titleText),
            subtitle: Text(subtitleText),
            trailing: Icon(trailingIcon),
          );
  }
```

Comment: how to add line ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ListTile` for each element and `Divider` between them

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    if (i.isOdd)
      return Divider();
    final index = i ~/ 2;
    return buildRow(index);
  },
  itemCount: [your_items].length * 2,
  controller: controller,
);

Widget buildRow(int index) {
  return ListTile(
    leading: /* your icon */,
    title: /* title */,
    subtitle: /* subtitle */,
    trailing: /* right arrow */,
  )
}
```